# Jar missing Sun classes

Tags: java, jar, intellij-idea

I've been writing some software, but I realised that I can't run the jar because it is missing some classes, while it is running fine straight from the IDE. The jar is built in the latest IntelliJ Idea Community Edition. This is the error it gives me when I try to run it using "java -jar".

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/plugin/dom/exception/InvalidStateException
        at ro.mihalea.abstractInput.mothership.Main.main(Main.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.plugin.dom.exception.InvalidStateException
```

I started from the command used by the IDE to run it and I removed as many classes as I could and I was left with this command.

```
java  -cp "Mothership.jar:C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\lib\plugin.jar;E:\Programming\Java\IntelliJ Idea\abstractINPUT\out\production\Mothership;E:\Programming\Java\IntelliJ Idea\abstractINPUT\Mothership\lib\*;E:\Programming\Java\IntelliJ Idea\abstractINPUT\out\production\Shared" ro.mihalea.abstractInput.mothership.Main
```

Without the first two dependencies coming from the JRE, the program would not start.  When I remove them I get the error described above. I don't know why I need to link them manually when they are already in the JRE.

Comment: Intellij is probably referencing the libraries automatically within the IDE, but not when the jar is run outside of intellij.

Comment: Could you show us that code?  Are you using a `sun/plugin/dom/exception/InvalidStateException`?

Comment: The docs promise that extensions will be autoloaded (typically jre/lib/ext), but I don't see a guarantee that everything under jre/lib also gets loaded by default

Comment: @tieTYT, I was uploading snippets of code to pastebin when I realised I was throwing InvalidStateException in some places. I removed them and now I can finally run it outside of the IDE. Thank you for your help, and I'm sorry for bothering you, but I'm still a newbie.

Answer (score 3):

I removed any occurrences of InvalidStateException in my code, and now it runs flawless.